# How to return Two separate lists of different column from Resultset in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

Actually I am new in My batis and wanted to help me out in bellow scenario

I wanted to return Object Which has two list as a member, from  Result of select Query in Mybatis.
for example  my object Class

```
    public class ABC{
    List Boys;
    List Girls;
}
```

And I wanted to generate single instance of ABC from  bellow Query

```
Select Boy_roll_no , Boy_name, Girl_roll_no , Girl_name from Classdata
```

Can anybody help me out how to do xml configuration(How to define resultmap for query ) for Mybatis

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can return such a complex object from MyBatis. Generally MyBatis will return "list of objects" that can be beans but, as far as I know, there is no way to return "object of lists". What you have to do is make two separate queries that return the boy's list and the girl's list and in your business logic put both in your ABC object.
Hope this helps you.